# How are convergence tests proved?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is it intuitive or are there formal methods for why do convergence tests work?

Comment: This is too broad. Do you have a specific test in mind?

Comment: D'Alembert's test,Raabe's test etc

Comment: Textbooks in analysis do include proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Convergence test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests) is just a name to denote a series of theorems which of course are specifically proved in rigorous and formal way.

Refer also to [**Convergence Tests Proofs**](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Category:Convergence_Tests).

Comment: I wanted to ask, how do we know they work? In my Math classes, there is no proof given, only theorem statements..So how did the mathematicians arrive at those tests?

Comment: @KrishnaDeshmukh: Find some better math classes to attend.

Comment: Ha. Can you provide some sources?Like online or books.

Comment: @KrishnaDeshmukh As already explained they are called "test" as a name but of course they are theorems. I've added a link with many proof.

Comment: @HenningMakholm LoL! That's a good suggestion!

Comment: gimusi,Thankyou..

Comment: Are there any video tutorials for the proofs?Khan Academy does not have the proofs.

Comment: @KrishnaDeshmukh I don't know any specific source, but of course you can find something on the web!